# JdbcTemplate.execute or update hangs while simple Connection.createStatement().execute works fine

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have spring application where I'm using JdbcTemplate to perform sql queries to Postgres. I need to execute several sql statements in a row and some of the statements (randomly) make jdbcTemplate method hangs for about 30 minutes (sql return ~90 rows and executes in DBeaver for 1 sec).

Why this happens? Why Connection works fine and jdbcTemplate not?

I'm using such construction:

```
transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult {
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.execute(sql)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        log.error("...")
    }
}
```

And exactly the same code, replacing `jdbcTemplate.execute(sql)` with defined Connection works fine

```
val cur = DriverManager.getConnection(...).createStatement()

transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult {
    try {
        cur.execute(sql)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        log.error("...")
    }
}
```

Sql is something like `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM (select ...) t`

By the way, project is written in kotlin

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets to analyse?

Comment: @SanketSingh, added some more info